# How to create multiple XElements from html string in c#

Tags: c#, html, xml

I am creating an XML object in c# and have html strings that I would like to parse into XElements in order to insert them, however I do **not** want to have to wrap them in a parent element as they are intended to be inserted into one already.

Html:

```
<p>Hello world</p><br /><p>Second <b>Line</b></p>
```

Intended Xml:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<br />
<p>Second <b>Line</b></p>
```

At the moment the only way I can do this is if I use code below, however I don't want the outer tag

```
XElement.Parse("<parenttag>" + html + "</parenttag>")
```

**NB**. These elements will be inserted into a parent element to form correct xml, **my intended output for this html string is an array of xml elements** ( ie 2 p elements and a br)

Comment: If you are going to downvote please provide some context, I am unaware of what is wrong with this question.. is it against rules of xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've parse the string successfully by wrapping in an outer tag you should call `.Elements()` which will return the children on the element.

```
var html = "<p>Hello world</p><br /><p>Second <b>Line</b></p>";
var root = XElement.Parse("<parenttag>" + html + "</parenttag>")
var children = root.Elements();
// children.Count() == 3
```

Comment: Cheers this worked. For some reason completely avoided checking the properties of the root element, thanks.