# Parse partial XML string to list of XElements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a partial XML string without a root element. E.g.:

```
<Item Id="1">some text</Item>
<Item Id="2">some other text</Item>
```

I need to convert this string to a list of XElements.

Is there a way to do this without adding a dummy root element or splitting the string?

Comment: Easiest way is to add a root using strings : <root> + xmlString + </root>

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482667/parse-partial-xml-string-to-list-of-xelements#comment121030130_68482667) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31561321/109941):

```
var myPartialXmlString = @"
<Item Id=""1"">some text</Item>
<Item Id=""2"">some other text</Item>
";
var xElements = XElement.Parse($"<root>{myPartialXmlString}</root>").Elements();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `XElement.Parse`? [Microsoft XElement Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Yes, that gives a XmlException "There are multiple root elements.".

Comment: I don't see any options other than a root element or a complex parse and split function. @jdweng gave a good answer